# Different locations in different browsers

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

Why is that locations differs regarding the browser?

- Chrome / Firefox : Same location from 30 kms from where I'm
- IE : from 250 kms from where I'm
- Safari : Exactly where I'm

How can Safari detect where I'm and the others can't?

Is the

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
```

The best way to get users current position from a Browser?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked on my browser to see if i had the same result you had.

Unfortunately, the result i had was the same on *Safari*, *Firefox* and *Chrome*. It gave me my exact current Position.

On IE 10 and IE9 the result just differ from a couple of meters of where I was actually.

The navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() methods just try to locate you with Data like IP Address and WiFi signals. On some devices, that can use the GPS signals if the device is equip with a GPS module.

The trick is that GPS signals are generally less acurate than WiFi signals. But i don't think that show why there is a difference between your browser.

Maybe you can try to use the **enableHighAccuracy:true** parameter for the **getCurrentPosition** to see if the result differs again between each browsers.